# Sending a file name to a qt tabWidget from main window's menu

Tags: c++, qt

I am using qt to build a file editor with multiple tabs, each tab corresponds to a single file. In mainwindow.cpp I have the function:

```
    void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
    {

        QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open File","/home",tr("*.ext"));
    }
```

and I need to send fileName to a new tab for my tab widget. I know there are signals and slots for classes in qt but I can't for the life of me figure out how to send the QString to a specific tab. Is there some way of sending the filename to the tab's creation event, or possibly use the tab's index for sending it a signal?

I am very new to qt but I'm fairly sure this should be a simple process. I just cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: full modified code with both as members of mainwindow:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
    {
    if (fileName!=NULL)
        {
        int curtab=ui->fileTabWidget->addTab(new my_editor,tr("editor"));
        ui->fileTabWidget->setCurrentIndex(curtab);
        }
    }
```

So following @vizhanyolajos instructions; if I pass the filename to the end of addTab, where do I need to add the rest of the code for recieving it?

I'm assuming in my custom editor class.

Comment: there's plenty of ways. Can you add your tab creation code?

Comment: @deW1 Added above. Please let me know if you would like the class declaration as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no tab creation event. You need to do the following steps, and I think you don't need any SIGNAL/SLOT mechanism for this. I think that the SLOT what you included in your question is a member function of you QMainWindow. And I think your QTabWidget is also part of your QMainWindow so you only need to do this:

```
void onActionTriggered()
{
    const QString filename = // ...

    ui.TabWidget->addTab( /* Your custom class derived from QWidget or a Qt widget */, filename );
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I need, I would then just setup the class to have that extra parameter correct?

Comment: In your modified code, you should change the ( fileName != NULL ) to the previously used QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( ... ) and then check if ( ! fileName.isEmpty() ). After that pass that fileName to the addTab( ... ) as the second argument. If your custom widget also needs the fileName then pass that to it also new my_editor( fileName ).

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look something like this for example:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open File","/home",tr("*.ext"));

    createNewPage( index , name , fileName );
}


createNewPage( int index , QString name , QString fileName )
{
    // your page creation code goes here
    // your fileOpen and fill textBox code goes here where you can use the fileName for it
}
```

I would recommend you store your pageIndex + fileName in a container so you can easily query which page corresponds to which file.

---

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open File","/home",tr("*.ext"));

    if (fileName!=NULL)
    {
        ui->fileTabWidget->addTab(new my_editor( fileName ),tr("editor"));
        ui->fileTabWidget->setCurrentIndex(curtab);
    }
 }
```

Just pass the `fileName` to the constructor of your `my_editor` Widget.
In there you can call your function for filling your editor with the `fileName` then.

Comment: @MoffD updated my post. If anything else is unclear let me know.

Comment: I apreciate the help, I used vizhanyolajos's method of using addTab(/*class data*/, fileName)